# Como puedo mostrar palabras concretas en distintos colores en angular js

Tags: angularjs

lo que quiero hacer es mostrar la palabra aprobado en verde y no aprobado en rojo.

mi codigo es:

```
<div ng-if="data.student_status=='Aprobado'">
<b class="verde" ng-show="{{data.student_status}}"></b>
</div>

<div ng-if="data.student_status=='No Aprobado'">
<b class="rojo" ng-show="{{data.student_status}}"></b>
</div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.params = $state.params;
$scope.imagesfolder = config.urlBase+'images';
$scope.students = "";
$http.get(config.urlBase+'json/data_students')
.success(function(data, status, headers,config){
console.log('Data students success');
$scope.data = data.students[$state.params.id];
$scope.students= data.students;
$ionicLoading.hide();
})

.error(function(data, status, headers,config){
console.log('Data students error');
$ionicLoading.show();
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucion

```
<b ng-class="{'verde': data.student_status === 'Aprobado', 'rojo': data.student_status === 'No Aprobado'}">{{data.student_status}}</b>
```

Comment: Me alegra que encontraras solucion. pero te recomiendo que formules la respuesta como si fuera otro quien la hubiera respondido. Con explicacion detallada de qué tenia mal en la pregunta y cómo la respuesta funciona. Un saludo ^^ (en 48h puedes aceptar la respuesta)

Comment: Acepta cuando puedas tu propia solución para que pueda servir en un futuro a otros.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas,

No entiendo bien que haces en el controlador, con el response del la petición $http, pero te date un ejemplo del html y SASS :

SCSS:

```
.estudiantes {
   .aprobado {color: #00A600};
   .reprobado {color: #FF0000};
 }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="estudiantes" ng-repeat = "estudiante in data" >
   <h4 ng-class="{'aprobado': data.student_status === "Aprobado", 'reprobado': data.student_status === "Reprobado"}">
       {{data.student_status}}
  </h4> 
</div>
```

Ojala te sirva, saludos, sino usas SASS es casi igual que CSS, pero te da muchas ventajas, **te recomiendo aprenderlo**, cuando lo usas ya no dejas de usarlo.

Saludos.